# what is the equivalent of a reduce in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a backend dev moved recently onto js side. I was going through a tutorial and came across the below piece of code.

```
clickCreate: function(component, event, helper) {
    var validExpense = component.find('expenseform').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
        // Displays error messages for invalid fields
        inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
        return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
    }, true);
    // If we pass error checking, do some real work
    if(validExpense){
        // Create the new expense
        var newExpense = component.get("v.newExpense");
        console.log("Create expense: " + JSON.stringify(newExpense));
        helper.createExpense(component, newExpense);
    }
}
```

Here I tried to understand a lot on what's happening, there is something called `reduce` and another thing named `validSoFar`. I'm unable to understand what's happening under the hood. :-(

I do get the regular loops stuff as done in `Java`.

Can someone please shower some light on what's happening here. I should be using this a lot in my regular work.

Thanks

Comment: Does the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) not help?

Comment: Here's your Java equivalent ~ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html

Comment: @LucaKiebel, thanks for the quick response. I tried that, but I was unable to get it. If I can see my code in `classic` way(using `loops`), that can be helpful to match and understand.  Thanks Again!!!

Comment: On that same page there is an example of the function with just loops: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill

Comment: #pseudo: valid = true, foreach input in expenseform, if input.validity = false, valid = false. So basically it loops over all the inputs. If one of the inputs is invalid, the entire result becomes invalid.

Comment: @Phil, Thank you very much. But this is having some streams concepts. I'm looking for some piece that is equivalent to the classic coding pattern :(

Comment: @RakeshK This is functional programming, you won't easily find equivalents to "classic coding pattern"

Comment: Look at the polyfill on the MDN document, it shows you how it is done with a loop....

Comment: @RakeshK It's just reducing the array to a single boolean value, which initially is true (second parameter of reduce). Other than that, "validSoFar" is the **current** value of the accumulator (again, initially true). After that it just evaluates: `validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid`, which will result in a **boolean** value, which will be the next **current** value (so, `validSoFar` value) of the next iteration, until it ends. It's like a for cycle, where the nth looped value is "validSoFar" and the nth + 1 value is the "inputCmp" value, despite they have different types.

Answer (score 0):

The reduce function here is iterating through each input component of the expense form and incrementally mapping to a boolean. If you have say three inputs each with a true validity, the reduce function would return:

1. `true && true` where the first true is the initial value passed into reduce.
2. `true && true` and where the first true here is the result of the previous result.
3. `true && true`

At the end of the reduction, you're left with a single boolean representing the validity of the entire, where by that if just a single input component's validity is false, the entire reduction will amount to false. This is because `validSoFar` keeps track of the overall validity and is mutated by returning the compound of the whether the form is valid so far and the validity of the current input in iteration.

Comment: Hi Callam, I have not heard from you on CodeMentor. Please let me know when you have the time for a session. I will delete this comment after you read it . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to use reduce there and have side effects in the reduce. Better use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get all invalid expense items.

Then use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to produce side effect(s) for each invalid item. You can then check the length of invalid expense items array to see it your input was valid:

```
function(component, event, helper) {
  var invalidExpenses = component.find('expenseform').filter(
    function(ex){
      //return not valid (!valid)
      return !ex.get('v.validity').valid
    }
  );
  invalidExpenses.forEach(
    //use forEach if you need a side effect for each thing
    function(ex){
      ex.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
    }
  );
  // If we pass error checking, do some real work
  if(invalidExpenses.length===0){//no invalid expense items
      // Create the new expense
      var newExpense = component.get("v.newExpense");
      console.log("Create expense: " + JSON.stringify(newExpense));
      helper.createExpense(component, newExpense);
  }
}
```

The [mdn documentation for Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) has a good description and examples on how to use it.

It should take an array of things and return one other thing (can be different type of thing). But you won't find any examples there where side effects are initiated in the reducer function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonable equivalent:

```
var validExpense = true;
var inputCmps = component.find('expenseform')
for (var i = 0; i < inputCmps.length; i++) {
    // Displays error messages for invalid fields
    inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
    if (!inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid) {
        validExpense = false;
    }
}
// Now we can use validExpense
```

This is a somewhat strange use of `reduce`, to be honest, because it does more than simply reducing a list to a single value.  It also produces side effects (presumably) in the call to `showHelpMessageIfInvalid()`.

The idea of `reduce` is simple.  Given a list of values that you want to fold down one at a time into a single value (of the same or any other type), you supply a function that takes the current folded value and the next list value and returns a new folded value, and you supply an initial folded value, and `reduce` combines them by calling the function with each successive list value and the current folded value.

So, for instance,

```
var items = [
  {name: 'foo', price: 7,  quantity: 3},
  {name: 'bar', price: 5,  quantity: 5},
  {name: 'baz', price: 19, quantity: 1}
]

const totalPrice = items.reduce(
  (total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, // folding function
  0  // initial value
); //=> 65
```

Comment: The for loop would be more like `for (var i = 0; i < inputCmps.length; i++) {
    validExpense=validExpense&&inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid
}` as used in the reducer (accum&&currentValid)

Comment: @HMR: I think that's equivalent.